# Why is my new Shapefile layer not showing up?

Tags: qgis

I am having trouble with a new shape layer not showing up on my map. The attribute table is showing up fine and all of the points are in there, however visually, there are no dots showing on the map. I have made sure that the new shape layer was at the very top of the stack. I tried placing the new shape layer on a blank new project and it worked perfectly as it should. Then I re-opened the original problem project, deleted all of the existing layers, saved it as temp with no data in it at all, and then closed and re-opened the project and re-loaded the problem shape layer into the new temp project. It did not show up again.

I have gone back to my original data and re-created the csv that I initially used to create the shape file (did this a couple of times), in case there was some spurious content in there, however, this had no effect, and the problem remains.

Using QGIS 1.8.0 and Windows 7 64-bit. However I installed QGIS onto a Linux machine and the identical problem occurred.

Hope someone can help, or has an idea what it might be...

Comment: If you can share the shapefile, others can investigate. Most probably the layer CRS is set to EPSG:4326 (latlon degrees), showing no results if the data contains projected coordinates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you got error in both OS and you can see the information on attribute table, maybe there is a problem with the Coordinate Reference System (CRS).

- First, when you created the shapefile through "Add Delimited Text Layer" tool, did you assign the CRS?;
- Second, when you create the project, are you sure that all layers are
  in the same CRS; If do not, did you activated the option "Enable on
  the fly CRS tranformation" on the Project Properties window?

[image: CRS tab]

Comment: Thank you! I checked the CRS of the existing layers and made sure the new one matched. I had set it as GDA94 instead of GDA94 / MGA zone 55 (which is what the rest of the layers were set to ... I am in Tasmania Australia). Now it works!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the layer, Zoom to layer. 
Once you are there, are the coordinates realistic?

Answer (score 0):

I came upon the Question for answers but was able to solve it with an other solution.
So my case of shapefile "dissapearing" was due to corrupted .qml file. I was able to fix it by re-building and load the .qml file as new.