# QTiles generating blank tiles on QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles

I need to generate tiles from shape files (which contain contour lines) I've loaded into QGIS. 
I'm trying to use the QTiles plugin to generate these tiles, but when I run it, it only generates blank tiles.

Following settings used:
Output: Directory
Extent: Canvas Extent
Zoom: 10 - 12
Quality: Use TMS tiles convention

It almost looks like the canvas extent has not been selected properly?
It seems like I'm missing something small. Possibly a decent tutorial will also help.
I'm new to QGIS and I'm using 2.8.3-Wein on Ubuntu.

I've tried generating tiles with the [natural earth oceans vector](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110m-ocean/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I am also a newbie. I encountered the same problem. I tried to change the coordinate reference allocated to the area I am interested in but the tile appears blank and located rather far from the geo-referenced area. I am in Timor-Leste (East Timor) therefore I use the WGS 84/UTM Zone 51s. I have also tried 52s but didn't work. Have I missed any important steps? Help please.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. If you have not already done so, please take the [tour] to learn about the site's focused Q&A format. Please be sure any answers attempt to address the OPs questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by taking a hint from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43676/why-is-my-new-shapefile-layer-not-showing-up) post.

The problem seemed to have been that my shape files did not have the appropriate coordinate reference system (CRS) set.

I fixed this by selecting all of the layers, **right-click > Properties**
Then went to Coordinate reference system section and select the correct CRS in the drop down.

On doing the next Qtiles generation my shapes were rendered.

Comment: 4+ year old answer solved my problem. Love it when that happens, and thank you!